# delete kafka consumer offset with new consumer api

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to delete a consumer offset when using the new consumer API?

`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` outputs:

`WARNING: Group deletion only works for old ZK-based consumer groups, and   one has to use it carefully to only delete groups that are not active.`

Answer (score 0):

The only way: manually send to __consumer_offsets topic message with correct key and payload=null.

Kafka will delete all consumers data in some time (set by **offsets.retention.minutes**). By default is 24 hours.